# Behaviors SDK Not available in Vs2017

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, behavior

I've developed a UWP project with **Behaviors SDK** in VS2015 (Windows 10).

Then I've installed VS2017 and tried to run the app without any changes. Unfortunately I'm getting below error for **Behaviors SDK**.

Are there any solution or workaround for this problem?

**Reference Image:**

[image: Behavior SDK Reference]

**Error Output:**

- error MSB3774: Could not find SDK "BehaviorsXamlSDKManaged, Version=12.0"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/) nuget package instead (or [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Native](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Native/) if you develop your application in C++). The source code of these packages are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors).

Behaviors SDK was created for WinRT projects (Windows 8.0/8.1). Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed package seems to be a recommended replacement for the Behaviors SDK for the UWP applications (even in VS2015).